# Run a testNG test suite with a jar / no runnable method

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, testng, program-entry-point

I need your help ! 
At work I'll need to automate tests to test an entire application. Point is, I am beginner at Java and at automation.

I am trying different tutorial and it works good. But now, I wanna progress. I will need to deliver my tests but as .jar. 
And it doesn't work, because i need a main class. I am trying to add it, but it doesn't work.

I **UPDATED** my scripts to correct and simplified them but I am still having some problems. Now I have :

A main class to launch the test :

```
package nouguierc.selenium;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Running tests!");
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { RegistrationTest.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}
}
```

I have the warning message : "The method addListener from the type testNG is deprecated"

I have also the test I want to exec (and put as a runnable jar also) :

```
package nouguierc.selenium;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class RegistrationTest{

public  ExtentReports extent;
public  ExtentTest test;
public  int a = 1;
WebDriver driver=null;

@Test //This is TestNG annotation

public void testRegister(){

        extent = ExtentManager.Instance();


                    try{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\nouguierc\\Desktop\\Projets\\Testing\\Airbus\\Automatisation\\testCélia\\WD_Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

        test = extent.startTest("VerificationReporting", "AlorsAlors");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("User1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("Surname1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("123456789");
        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("Test Address");
        driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Test City");
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("ANGOLA");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("user1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("user1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();

        if(a == 1)
            test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "OK" );
        else
            test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "NOT OK" );

        driver.quit();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            driver.quit();
        }

    extent.endTest(test);
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}   

}
```

And my POM.xml is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>StackOverFlow</groupId>
<artifactId>StackOverFlow</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.version>1.7</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>nouguierc.selenium.TestRunner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>nouguierc.selenium.TestRunner</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.13.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

When I exec the test on Eclipse, I have this result :

```
Running tests!
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

And when I export the jar thanks to Eclipse and run it with the cmd I have :

```
no manifest attribute in ExecutableJAR.jar
```

The test is opening google chrome to the adress "data;" and doing nothing. Then I have the following failed result :

```
testRegister java.lang.NullPointerException
at nouguierc.selenium.RegistrationTest.testRegister(RegistrationTest.java:61)
at nouguierc.selenium.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:13)
... Removed 22 stack frames
```

When I remove the line "driver.quit();" in the catch. The test is passed successfully but that's not normal because it happend nothing in google chrome. It should be K.O.

Maybe someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the property for chromedriver and put chromedriver.exe at your project level.

To run it as a jar you have to create a main class also :

```
package com.stack.JarCreation;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { RunnableJar.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
    }
}
```

[image]

```
package com.stack.JarCreation;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RunnableJar {
    public int a = 1;

    @Test
    public void testRegister() {
        WebDriver driver=null;
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("User1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("Surname1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("123456789");
            driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
            driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("Test Address");
            driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Test City");
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
            select.selectByVisibleText("ANGOLA");
            driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("user1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("user1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();

            if (a == 1)
                System.out.println("OK");
            else
                System.out.println("NOT OK");
            driver.quit();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

If it is not a maven project , convert it into maven project by Right clicking on your project and go to configure->convert to Maven project.

And replace your pom.xml with below file.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>StackOverFlow</groupId>
    <artifactId>StackOverFlow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.stack.JarCreation.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.stack.JarCreation.Main</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.13.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Create the Jar for Launch Configuration as Main-StackOverflow and put jar and chromedriver.exe at same location.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will test it. But what is geckodriver ? I though it should launch firefox by default.

Comment: I tested it. I have the error :
"Jar export finished with problems. See details
Could not find main method from given launch configuration".

The MANIFEST.MF does not contain the main class (TestRunner). I don't understand why. In the jar, there isn't my main method, and my TestSuite and RegistrationTest neither.

Comment: If you are using Selenium 3 then to work with Firefox browser you need to use separate  driver which will interact with Firefox browser. If you have noticed then we have done the same thing for Chrome and IE browser as well.

Comment: Do you want to create a jar and run it or you are running it on eclipse?
Could you please eloborate what is the actual issue and can you attach the failure report with the above code because it worked fine for me.

Comment: It works when I run TestRunner on Eclipse. But it doesn't work when I export the runnable jar and whrite "java -jar "ExecutableJar.jar"" in the cmd. I edited my post.

Comment: There were some dependencies missing in pom.xml which i have added and it needed a main class to run as a jar which i have added . Take the **latest edited code** and create the jar. I tried it and it is running successfully for me.
If it works for you please accept the solution.

Comment: With all the dependencies I have the following error when executing in eclipse : JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 654: aUrl is undefined

Comment: My bad, I found a mistake. But now I have the error (in Eclipse) : 
testRegister(nouguierc.selenium.RegistrationTest)
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Eclipse don't enable me to write : driver = new ChromeDriver();. I need to write : WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); if i don't want an error.

And in Exception e I can't write driver.quit (driver cannot be resolved)

Comment: Ok problem with driver, webdriver etc is fixed. But I have the same error. java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Errors i get : 
JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 654: aUrl is undefined
AND THEN :
There was 1 failure:
1) testRegister(nouguierc.selenium.RegistrationTest)
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at nouguierc.selenium.RegistrationTest.testRegister(RegistrationTest.java:59)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 etc etc

Comment: From where you are running your code. 
Could you please share your code so that i can have a look at it.

Comment: When you are getting the error , while running it through Eclipse or by jar.
Do you have jar and chromedriver.exe both at the same location?

Comment: Check if you are sending test class name(which contains test cases) in Main class at below line

testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { **RunnableJar**.class });

where RunnableJar is the name of the class which contains the Test case.

And I tried it again on another system and it is working fine. **Just try one more thing copy my entire code with the same structure and try to run**. Hope it would work for you.

Comment: When I launch the script. Chrome is openning and there is "data:," in the adress field. And it's doing nothing.

Comment: I'm not getting why it is not working for you. Could you please share your code?

Comment: I am updating my code in the main post :) Normally you can understand better my problem now

Comment: When I don't have any error, it happend nothing on google Chrome. And the test is passed. That's not normal.

Comment: Rename your main class name , you can't give the name **TestRunner**, give any name like **MainJar** and while creating the jar choose this class as Launch configuration. and replace your RegistrationTest class and pom.xml by the class i'm providing in the next comment.

Comment: I dont' have enough reputation to put helpful ;)

Comment: Do you still have any confusion?

Comment: I always have confusions in this work environment ahah ! I post another question if you are interested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231506/error-when-performing-selenium-connexion-test-undefined-to-be-a-string/43234028?noredirect=1#comment73562966_43234028

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: Did you find something ?

Answer (score 0):

RegistrationTest class :

```
package nouguierc.selenium;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RegistrationTest {
    public int a = 1;

    @Test
    public void testRegister() {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\nouguierc\\Desktop\\Projets\\Testing\\Airbus\\Automatisation\\testCélia\\WD_Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("User1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("Surname1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("123456789");
            driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
            driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("Test Address");
            driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Test City");
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
            select.selectByVisibleText("ANGOLA");
            driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1@test.com");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("user1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("user1");
            driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();

            if (a == 1)
                System.out.println("OK");
            else
                System.out.println("NOT OK");
            driver.quit();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>StackOverFlow</groupId>
    <artifactId>StackOverFlow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>nouguierc.selenium.MainJar</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>nouguierc.selenium.MainJar</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.13.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please Replace these two file of yours by the files I just provided here and name the main class as **MainJar**

Comment: Read last comment on the first answer also which i have provided.

Comment: Is it worked? If it is then please accept the solution to close this discussion.