# Error when performing selenium connexion test ( undefined to be a string )

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

I have the error : Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
And I don't know how to fix it.
I don't know how to fix it and I don't know either where to search a potential error.

Firefox is launched but didn't perform anything expect going to the site.

My variables paramTest2, paramTest3, paramTest4... are empty and I don't understand why ... There is just paramTest1 which contain something and this is the web adress.

Here is the full trace :

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Temp\testng-eclipse--806319973\testng-customsuite.xml

###################################################
##### TEST : Connexion
##### DESCRIPTION : Test sur la connexion
###################################################
1491402504078   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:13254
1491402504745   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path    C:\Temp\rust_mozprofile.IGVKHcaTXwv0
1491402504751   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Nightly\firefox.exe with args []
1491402504759   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:60098
1491402505513   Marionette  WARN    Deprecated preference marionette.defaultPrefs.enabled detected, please use marionette.enabled
[GPU 7556] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-cen-w64-ntly-000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,   line 346
[Child 11252] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-cen-w64-ntly-  000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,   line 346
[Child 11252] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-cen-w64-ntly-000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1491402507490   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 60098
1491402507875   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
avr. 05, 2017 4:28:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake  createSession
INFOS: Detected dialect: W3C
Connexion au site : https://wd3-impl.workday.com/ag_preview/login.htmld?redirect=n
Connexion à l'espace client
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\Default suite\Default test0.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED: testCas("Connexion", "testcases\testcase1.csv", "Test sur la connexion")
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'TOLX300092143', ip: '44.10.108.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Temp\rust_mozprofile.IGVKHcaTXwv0, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=55.0a1, platformVersion=6.1, moz:processID=7624, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: 44ae5d76-506f-4cd3-95c6-b11b71455bfd
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:43)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at      org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
at selenium.FindElements.connexionWD(FindElements.java:27)
at selenium.SeleniumTest.testEtape(SeleniumTest.java:105)
at selenium.SeleniumTest.testCas(SeleniumTest.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@13fee20c: 75 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@4cb2c100: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@5d624da6: 8 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\Default test.properties
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\index.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\main.html
 [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\groups.html
 [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html
 [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\reporter-output.html
 [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\methods-not-run.html
 [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1 \Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html
 [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old\index.html
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\old exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@5f2050f6: 44 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\junitreports\TEST-selenium.SeleniumTest.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\junitreports exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@77b52d12: 10 ms
 [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\ng647f1\Desktop\Worspaces_Automation\WD_Automation\WD_Automation_EXPORT\WD_Automation\test-output\Default suite exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 15 ms
```

Here is my script findElements :

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;


public class FindElements {

final WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@aria-label=\"Nom d'utilisateur\"]")
public WebElement PSEUDO;

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@aria-label='Mot de passe']")
public WebElement MDP;

@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "GDQYR4DOVK")
public WebElement CONNECT;

public FindElements(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

public void connexionWD(String EmailConnect, String MdpConnect){
    PSEUDO.sendKeys(EmailConnect);
    MDP.sendKeys(MdpConnect);
    CONNECT.click();
}

}
```

And here is my script SeleniumTest :

```
package selenium;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class SeleniumTest {

private static WebDriver driver = null;

@DataProvider(name = "testPlan")
public Object[][] motCles() throws IOException {
      //Lecture du plan de test avec Open CSV
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("testplan.csv"), ';', '"', 1);
             int i = 0;
             List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
             Object testPlan[][]= new Object[allRows.size()][3];
             for(String[] row : allRows){
                   testPlan[i][0] = row[0];
                   testPlan[i][1] = row[1];
                   testPlan[i][2] = row[2];
                   i++;
             }
             reader.close();
      return testPlan;
}


@Test(dataProvider = "testPlan")

public void testCas(String nomTest, String lienTest, String descTest) throws Exception {

        //Lecture du cas de test avec OpenCSV
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(lienTest), ';', '"', 1);

        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionnette","C:\\Users\\ng647f1\\Desktop\\Worspaces_Automation\\WD_Automation\\WD_Automation_EXPORT\\WD_Automation\\geckodriver.exe");

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        System.out.println("###################################################");
        System.out.println("##### TEST : " + nomTest);
        System.out.println("##### DESCRIPTION : " + descTest);
        System.out.println("###################################################");

        List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
        String testDescription[][]= new String[50][21];

        //Sélection du navigateur utilisé pour le test en cours. Ce navigateur est défini dans les cas de tests.
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("proxyType", "pac");
        capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("browser.private.browsing.autostart", true); 

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

        //On agrandit la fenêtre de test pour éviter les problèmes d'invisibilité d'éléments avec ChromeDriver.
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //On définit le temps d'attente avant qu'un cas de test tombe en erreur quand un élément n'est pas trouvé.
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //On lit les paramètres du cas de test dans le fichier du plan de test
        for(String[] row : allRows){
              for(j = 0; j<=20; j++){
                     testDescription[i][j] = row[j];
              }
              if (testDescription[i][0] != null) {
                     //On lance le cas de test
                     testEtape(testDescription[i][0], testDescription[i][1], testDescription[i][2], testDescription[i][3], testDescription[i][4], testDescription[i][5], testDescription[i][6], testDescription[i][7], testDescription[i][8], testDescription[i][9], testDescription[i][10], testDescription[i][11], testDescription[i][12], testDescription[i][13], testDescription[i][14], testDescription[i][15], testDescription[i][16], testDescription[i][17], testDescription[i][18], testDescription[i][19], testDescription[i][20]);
              }
              i++;
        }
        driver.quit();
        reader.close();     
}

// Interprétation des mots-clés

public void testEtape(String motCle, String paramTest1, String paramTest2, String paramTest3, String paramTest4, String paramTest5, String paramTest6, String paramTest7, String paramTest8, String paramTest9, String paramTest10, String paramTest11, String paramTest12, String paramTest13, String paramTest14, String paramTest15, String paramTest16, String paramTest17, String paramTest18, String paramTest19, String paramTest20) throws Exception {    

    //On initialise les classes des pages avec PageFactory
    FindElements FindElements1 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FindElements.class);

    //Pour chaque mot clé, des actions sont lancées. Certaines de ces actions sont des fonctions définies dans les classes des pages
    switch(motCle.toUpperCase()){ 
        case "ALLER":
            System.out.println("Connexion au site : " + paramTest1);
            driver.get(paramTest1);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        break;
        case "CONNEXION":
             System.out.println("Connexion à l'espace client");
             FindElements1.connexionWD(paramTest1, paramTest2);
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        break;
        default :
             System.out.println("||||| Mot clé non trouvé : " + motCle.toUpperCase());  
    }

}


}
```

My scripts use the two following csv files.

There is testplan.csv :

```
Nom;Fichier;Description
Connexion;testcases\\testcase1.csv;Test sur la connexion
```

Which contains just one test case for the moment, testcase1.csv :

```
Mot clé;Paramètre 1;Paramètre 2;Paramètre 3;Paramètre 4;Paramètre 5;Paramètre 6;Paramètre 7;Paramètre 8;Paramètre 9;Paramètre 10;Paramètre 11;Paramètre 12;Paramètre 13;Paramètre 14;Paramètre 15;Paramètre 16;Paramètre 17;Paramètre 18;Paramètre 19;Paramètre 20
ALLER;https://wd3-impl.workday.com/ag_preview/login.htmld?redirect=n;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
CONNEXION;thisIsMySecret@email;MySecretPassword;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I hope that one of you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like selenium isn't keeping up with WebDriver...

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users

> From your stacktrace it looks like Selenium is sending the wrong  JSON
>   body to geckodriver.  geckodriver expects
>
> ```
>     {text: "string"}
> ```
>
> whereas RemoteWebElement.java in Selenium sends
>
> ```
>     {value: ["s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]}
> ```
>
> I would file a bug with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want method `testEtape` to be called inside `testCas` but not as a separate test, then remove `@Test` from `testEtape`.

Comment: Yeah ! It works for the "testEtape requires 21 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation" error but not for the error "Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string"

Comment: probably try using `testDescription[i][0].toString` while calling `testEtape` in `testCas` as `testEtape(testDescription[i][0].toString,testDescription[i][1].toString(), testDescription[i][2].toString()........);`

Comment: It didn't change anything

Comment: Try to print `paramTest1, paramTest2` in `testEtape` before calling `FindElements1.connexionWD(paramTest1, paramTest2);`

Comment: paramTest1 contains the web adress, paramTest2 is empty !

Comment: are those your desired values which you want to pass to connexionWD?

Comment: I think the problem comes from after the line : `//On lit les paramètres du cas de test dans le fichier du plan de test` But I don't know how to rewrite it

Comment: Do you need to call method `testEtape` in for loop for every value of `j` ?  I would suggest you to call this method only when all values of `testDescription[][]` are assigned.

Comment: I don't know if I need to. And I don't understand what you are saying. But there is some strange things in row[i]. In the first row there is "ALLER" in the second one there is the web adress, and then, it is empty. This informations are in the same row in my csv. And there is another row with "CONNEXION" and my email and password and it is not displayed. It is not normal...

Comment: okay I'd suggest you one thing, lets check while calling `testEtape` instead of `testDescription[i][1], testDescription[i][2],` use some dummy value like `"abc","xyz"` respectively

Comment: And what should I see ?

Comment: I want to check why it fails @ `PSEUDO.sendKeys(EmailConnect);`

Comment: `FAILED: testCas("Connexion", "testcases\testcase1.csv", "Test sur la connexion")
java.lang.NullPointerException` and mozilla is launched but didn't go to the site

Comment: It is not, you can access the home page but you can't connect without my client network. So you can try yes ! Maybe it won't work with all the navigator

Comment: When I print allRows, I get : `[[Ljava.lang.String;@3712b94, [Ljava.lang.String;@2833cc44]` What is this ??

Comment: When I try to get the type of variables : EmailConnect, MdpConnect, paramTest1, paramTest2... It send no result, no type. Why ? The problem is maybe there. What do you think ?

Comment: You can-not print allRows just like because it is a list.

Comment: No, it was for the previous problem I had

Comment: What should be your allRows  content?

Comment: what is your selnium version, geckodriver version and firefox version?

Comment: Firefox nightly, gecko the last one (i don't remember) and selenium 3.3.1

Comment: It's ok for allRows in fact. But I don't understand why paramTest1 etc don't return any type

Comment: plus one more thing: why are you using "webdriver.firefox.marionette" instead of "webdriver.gecko.driver"?

Comment: I found some things on internet about marionette. I had problem with the start of firefox at the beginning. And since it works like this I stayed like this. It isn't good ?

Comment: I'll post it on another question, is that fine?

Comment: Yes ! Where to you post it ?